# How can we store Connect CTR data in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-connect

I am trying to Store Amazon Connect CTR data in S3 for Visualizing in Amazon Quicksight but I don't know How to do it.
Is it Automatically stored or we need lambda to Put CTR data in S3?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the Solution. I have to use Connect Firehose as delivery to Put CTR data into S3.
Firehose catches data from Kineses Stream and put it into S3